# How should I add buffering to a gzip writer?

Tags: go, gzip

I noticed the gzip package [uses `bufio` internally](http://golang.org/src/pkg/compress/gzip/gunzip.go?s=643:668#L20) for reading gzipped files, but not for writing them. I know that buffering is important for I/O performance, so what is the proper way to buffer a gzip writer?

```
// ignoring error handling for this example
outFile, _ := os.Create("output.gz")

// Alternative 1 - bufio.Writer wraps gzip.Writer
gzipWriter, _ := gzip.NewWriter(outFile)
writer, _ := bufio.NewWriter(gzipWriter)

// Alternative 2 - gzip.Writer wraps bufio.Writer
writer, _ :=  bufio.NewWriter(outFile)
gzipWriter, _ := gzip.NewWriter(writer)

// Alternative 3 - replace bufio with bytes.Buffer
buf := bytes.NewBuffer()
gzipWriter, _ := gzip.NewWriter(&buf)
```

Also, do I need to Flush() the gzip writer or the bufio writer (or both) before closing it, or will closing it automatically flush the writer?

**UPDATE**: I now understand that *both* reads and writes are buffered with gzip. So buffering a `gzip.Writer` is really double buffering. @peterSO thinks this is redundant. @Steven Weinberg thinks double buffering may reduce the number of syscalls, but suggests benchmarking to be sure.

Comment: Why do so many people downvote this? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but if I did, it would be because I think it's silly to ask humans which of three bits of code performs the best.

Comment: The semantics of the three bits are completely different. That's what I'm trying to understand. Even if I benchmarked each method, I wouldn't know __why__ one was better than the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to use bufio is to wrap a writer with a high overhead for each call to write. This is the case for any writer that requires syscalls. In this case, your "outFile" is an OS file and each write is a syscall.

```
outFile, err := os.Create("output.gz")
defer outFile.Close()

buf := bufio.NewWriter(outFile)
defer buf.Flush()

gz := gzip.NewWriter(buf)
defer gz.Close()

io.Copy(gz, src)
return
```

In this case, we are grouping writes to outFile with bufio so as to avoid unnecessary syscalls. The order is src -> gzip -> buffer -> file.

Now, when we finish writing, we have multiple buffers that need to be closed. We need to tell gzip we are done so it can flush its buffers and write final information to the buffer.
Then we need to tell bufio.Writer we are done so it can write out its internal buffers that it was saving for the next batch write. Finally, we need to tell the OS we are done with the file.

This destruction happens in the opposite order of creation, so we can use defers to make it easier. On return, the defers are executed in reverse order so we know we are flushing in the proper order because the defers for destruction are right next to the function calls for creation.

Comment: `io.Copy` has it's own optimizations, including buffering: `buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)`. Don't use `bufio` with `io.Copy`.

Comment: So, this uses `bufio.NewWriter`. Is there another way to do this without `bufio.NewWriter`?

Comment: Since Stephen is copying to an unbuffered `gzip.Writer` here, does your advice about not mixing `bufio` and `io.Copy` still apply? Would that be double-buffering, because the outer `gzip.Writer` wraps an inner `bufio` buffer?

Comment: @y0ssar1an: Steven's example is copying to an `io.Writer`: `gz := gzip.NewWriter(bufio.NewWriter(outFile))`. `gz` is a buffered writer. Buffering is affected by both the size and the number of buffers. Double buffering uses two buffers to provide overlap between filling a buffer and writing the other full buffer to the device. Using both `bufio` and `io.Copy` is redundant buffering. We don't need to use two buffering schemes.

Comment: @peterSO, this is not necessarily the case. I don't know gzip, but if this were json, the number of out writes is unrelated to the number of in writes. The purpose here is to guard against gzip making more writes than necessary.

Comment: @yOssar1an, upon inspection of the gzip code, there are multiple instances where the number of out writes is not equal to the number of in writes. I would suggest doing some benchmarking to determine the effect of using vs not using it.